# typescript: Нужен тип который будет валидировать константы

Tags: typescript

У меня есть объект

```
const env = {
  APP_PORT: +process.env.APP_PORT!,
  NODE_ENV: process.env.NODE_ENV!,
}
```

Какой можно указать тип чтобы проверить что название ключа совпадало с переменной в proccess.env....

Comment: Никакой. Это не задача тайпскрипта.

Comment: Наверное можно написать какую-нибудь хитрую проверку для линтера